# "Auto-Assign" parameter values if object property name equates?

Tags: c#

Is it possible, within a method, if the parameter names match EXACTLY the object property names, to "auto-assign" the values?

As an example, assume that you have the following method, which uses the type **MyExample**:

```
public static void Foo (string String1, string String2)
{

//rather than doing declarative assignment
MyExample example = new MyExample();
MyExample.String1 = String1;

// Some magic  method, Reflection maybe?
MyExample example = SomeMethodThatLooksAtParametersAndAssigns();

}
```

Essentially, the parameter name in the above, **String1**, exactly matches a property name of the **MyExample** object. Rather than assigning them one by one, is there a way to automate this? I am looking to call the Foo method from a different method, look at the caller parameters, then do the assignment. So Foo is more or less a utility method and not related to any specific type.

To further complicate matters, is it possible to do in a generic fashion that does the same for every object/type?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with reflection. Retrieve the the property with the name of your string and set its value to whatever it is you want it to be. Look at `someObject.GetType().GetProperty(string1);`.

Comment: Thanks, but that is hardcoding a reference. And how would you pass in the calling method to look at the parameters?

Comment: You already know you're going to return an object of type `MyExample`, why would you not hardcode it?

Comment: Because I am trying to do it a generic fashion

Comment: Google for AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first solution would be to just create something like this:

```
public static void Foo (string string1, string string2) {
    MyExample example = new MyExample();
    var prop = example.GetType().GetProperty(string1, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if(prop != null && prop.CanWrite) {
         prop.SetValue(example, string1, null);
    }
}
```

This approach will create a new instance of the type `MyExample`, fetch the appropriate property and invoke it with the corresponding value.

or if you really want to make this more generic:

```
void Main()
{   
    Foo("x", "y");  
}

public static void Foo (string string1, string string2) {
   var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(y => y.Name == string1) != null);
   var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   var prop = type.GetProperty(string1, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
   if(prop != null && prop.CanWrite) {
        prop.SetValue(obj, string2, null);
   }

   Console.WriteLine ((obj as Test).x);
}

class Test {
    public String x {get; set; }
}
```

Output:

> y

This does the same as before, but also dynamically creates a new instance of the found type while searching for it throughout the assembly.

Comment: Thanks. But this still has the hardcoded MyExample type in the generic solution. I am looking to call the Foo method from a different method, look at the caller parameters, then do the assignment.

Comment: @user3010406: that was a remnant that shouldn't have been there. Look again, I believe it now is as you want.

Comment: How would you pass in the calling method as the argument from where to interrogate the types?

Comment: I have no idea what that question means, can you rephrase?

Comment: Is it possible to call Foo from another method, look at the parameters of that "parent" or calling method, and use these for the assignment? So Foo essentially would have 0 parameters, unless the calling method is somehow passed in.

Comment: You can call `Foo` from anywhere you want, just make sure the access modifiers are appropriate. Then you can pass in the parameters: the first parameter will be the property that you want to set and the second parameter is the value that you want to set the property to. Then `Foo` will look for a class that has this property and set its value to `string2`.

Comment: You need to pass parameters to `Foo`, otherwise you haven't specified what property you want to set or what value you want to set it to..